# Is there a way to report the wrong translation of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, localization

I was browsing Facebook in a language other than English, and I spotted an incorrect translation. My question is, how do I report that the translation is incorrect and send in the corrected version of the translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **How can I report bad translations?**
>
> If you see a bad translation on the site, you can downvote the string by searching for it in the Translations app and clicking on the 'x' next to the translation in question. You can also suggest an alternative translation, or vote up an existing translation. If the bad translation remains on the site, you can raise the problem with the Translator Community Group for your language. You can find join this group by clicking on the link on the right hand side of the Translations app. If the problem persists, [let us know](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact_us.php?id=228711980522477).

[Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/225730797473322/).

Comment: Great, thats a heads-up, will do so accordingly. Thanks!